# Python translate date to quarter in date format

Tags: python, pandas, date-format

I am currently using below to convert a date to a quarter it belongs to. But, the return is an object. How can I get quarter in date format?

```
quarter_date_type['TIME_FRAME'] = quarter_date_type['CALENDARMONTH'].dt.to_period('Q')
```

and the below to get Bi-Annual the date belongs to..

```
year_date_type['TIME_FRAME'] = pd.to_datetime(year_date_type['CALENDARMONTH']).dt.strftime('%Y').astype(str) + np.where(year_date_type['CALENDARMONTH'].dt.month.le(6), ' H1', ' H2').astype(str)
```

Sample code for: this is the Input df; CALENDARMONTH is in datetime64[ns]

```
month_date_type = {'CALENDARMONTH':['2020-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01']}
 
    
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(month_date_type)
```

Expected Result is: all columns to be in format datetime64[ns]

```
CALENDARMONTH   QUARTER
0   2020-01-01  2020 Q1
1   2020-03-01  2020 Q1
2   2020-04-01  2020 Q2
3   2020-05-01  2020 Q2
```

Please assist with appropriate solution.

TIA

Comment: can you please add sample input and expected output ?

Comment: please refer above for sample df and expected result

Comment: `.dt.floor('Q')`

Comment: @BeRT2me: Can you please help more with solution, new to python - i am tying to google right now as well..

Comment: Try this: `df['CALENDARMONTH'].dt.to_period('Q')`

Answer (score 0):

```
df["quarter"] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.CALENDARMONTH), freq='Q')
```

or As suggested by @r-beginners

```
df["quarter"] = pd.to_datetime(df.CALENDARMONTH).dt.to_period('Q')
```

result

```
    CALENDARMONTH   quarter
0   2020-01-01  2020Q1
1   2020-03-01  2020Q1
2   2020-04-01  2020Q2
3   2020-05-01  2020Q2
```

Comment: How to get Bi-Annual for the date? like H1 or H2 in date format?